# Dynamic values from mysql for graphs in html-codeigniter view

Tags: javascript, html, codeigniter, dynamic, graph

I have to display a simple graph on view page of codeiginter application made of html and java script.
I am getting db data as following:

```
<?php 
$usd=$this->db->query('select transaction_id, amount from transactions')->result_array();
echo "<pre>";print_r($usd);
exit;
?>
```

But I want to get the data in the following form:

```
data: [ [1, 1300], [2, 1600], [3, 1900], [4, 2100]]
```

How I can do this?So that I can pass the value in  for the graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Got the solution for it,

```
<?php 
$usd=$this->db->query('select transaction_id, amount from transactions')->result_array();
$str = '';
for($i=0; $i<count($usd); $i++){
    if($i!=0){
        $str = $str.', ['.$usd[$i]["transaction_id"].', '.$usd[$i]["amount"].']';
    }else{
        $str = $str.'['.$usd[$i]["transaction_id"].', '.$usd[$i]["amount"].']';
    }
}
?>
```

and then passing this last variable provide the value

```
[ [1, 1300], [2, 1600], [3, 1900], [4, 2100]]
```